# How to remove numbers from this string in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a situation where I need to remove (or substitute) N numbers when they are between literal characters.
For example:

00000ASEDF32434VSC

I need 32434 to be removed so that the output is:

00000ASEDFVSC

And if I want to substitute 32434 with XXXXX ?

How to do it using regexes?

EDIT

I chose a very stupid example.Sorry.
Consider this:

00000SQWDDWE12CSDCASEDF32434VSC

I need to substitute (or remove) only the pattern 32434.

In general case: if I have an alphanumeric string how to
remove a pattern of N (say 5) numbers when they are between
literal characters?

Thanks.

Comment: do you know N upfront? in my solution I used 5, but question is it dynamically depends on input or something you already know without guessing?

Answer (score 3):

> remove a pattern of N (say 5) numbers when they are between literal characters?

What do you mean by "literal characters"? Do you mean "letters"? The following removes a sequence of 5 digits (0-9) that are both preceded and followed by a letter.

```
$str =~ s/(?<=\pL)[0-9]{5}(?=\pL)//;
```

Free free to change `5` for a variable.

```
my $n = 5;
$str =~ s/(?<=\pL)[0-9]{$n}(?=\pL)//;
```

Since Perl 5.14+, you can use `\d` to mean `[0-9]` by using `/a`. (Without `/a`, `\d` matches over 400 different characters.)

```
$str =~ s/(?<=\pL)\d{5}(?=\pL)//a;
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a lookahead `(?=...)` and a lookbehind `(?<=...)` to assert that the numbers are preceded and followed by non-numbers. This would remove such enclosed numbers:

```
$str =~ s{ (?<=\D) (\d+) (?=\D) }{}xg;
```

We can give a different substitution, or even code that will be executed. Here for variable-length `X`:

```
$str =~ s{(?<=\D) (\d+) (?=\D)}{ "X" x length $1 }xge;
```

`/e` executed the substitution, and `x` is the underused repetition operator.

Here is a subroutine that returns the string with all such number sequences removed, with optional minimum and maximum lenth possible:

```
use Carp;
sub remove_numbers {
  my ($string, $min, $max) = @_;
  $min //= 1;
  $max //= "";
  croak qq(argument \$min is not valid) if $min =~ /[^0-9]/;
  croak qq(argument \$max is not valid) if $max =~ /[^0-9]/;
  $string =~ s/(?<=\D) (\d{$min,$max}) (?=\D)/"X" x length $1/xge;
  return $string;
}
```

The call

```
$str = remove_numbers($str, 5, 5);
```

would be equivalent to `$str =~ s/(?<=\D)(\d{5})(?=\D)/XXXXX/`. The call

```
$str = remove_numbers($str);
```

would be equivalent to my second code example.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to remove:

```
$str =~ s/([a-z]+)\d{5}([a-z]+)/\1\2/i;
```

and this to replace:

```
$str =~ s/([a-z]+)\d{5}([a-z]+)/\1XXXXX\2/i;
```

where 5 is how many numbers you must replace.

Comment: use `$1` and `$2` in the replacement part, *not* `\1` and `\2`

Comment: no, one gives you a warning `\1 better written as $1` http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#%5C1-better-written-as-%241

Comment: Hmm I always used the 'bad' version, but just did a little reading up and you're right - it's old syntax and not recommended.

Comment: and enabling warnings is *definitely* recommended

Comment: Komodo RX toolkit complaints when you use $1, and suggests to use \1. Go figure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out the relevant part to replace, then repack it.  I'm assuming it's just a single instance of numbers.  That way it doesn't matter how many, but you always replace with the same number of 'X's...

```
$str = "00000ASEDF32434VSC";

my($prefix, $digits, $suffix) = $str =~ /^(.*[a-z])(\d+)([a-z].*)$/i;

# Replace with X
$str = $prefix . ($digits =~ s/./X/g) . $suffix;

# Or remove
$str = $prefix . $suffix;
```

You probably want to make sure that the regex succeeded though!

In response to your edit: You actually want to remove a specific number...

```
$str = $str =~ s/^(.*[a-z])32434([a-z].*)$/$1XXXXX$2/i;
```

Or if you want 5 digits (this has already been answered)

```
$str = $str =~ s/^(.*[a-z])\d{5}([a-z].*)$/$1XXXXX$2/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str =~ s/[1-9]//g
```

This would remove all numbers 1-9. Would this work?

```
$str =~ s/(\D)\d\d*(\D)/$1$2/g
```

Should replace only if the numbers are between strings, but not too sure if it works.

Comment: They still want an `X` for each character replaced, I believe.  So you either extract the part between and shove it back in with the right number of `X`s or you can do one at a time until there are no more matches (since `X` is a legitimate alpha character.

Comment: @paddy this was an answer to the first part mainly. But is it clear the OP wants "X" or an arbitrary number (x as variable)

Comment: Oh true, I missed that part =)